# Error: It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs

Tags: docker, .net-core

When I run the command `docker run -i -t myProject` it shows error:

> It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
>     Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
>         https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

However, I do have the .NET Core SDK installed and the `PATH` is correct (followed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.1#no-net-core-sdks-were-detected).

What's more, my project only needs runtime .NET Core SDK.

Does anyone know what might be the issue?

When running dotnet --info I got:

.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.101
 Commit:    b377529961

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18363
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x86
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.1
  Commit:  a1388f194c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.101 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?  Is the `ENTRYPOINT` command referencing the correct path?

Comment: Yes. Just solved it: in dockerfile I had aspnetcore-runtime-2.0 but that version is not found. After I change to aspnetcore-runtime-2.2 it works for me.

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 is out of support as of last December.  You should consider upgrading to 3.1.  See https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core for the latest supported images.

Answer (score 108):

For me it happened when I had wrong `ENTRYPOINT` in my `DOCKERFILE`

```
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleAppForDocker.dll"]
```

Make sure that you run correct dll in your `ENTRYPOINT`. I had wrong name of `dll` file.

Comment: "Double check what you're trying to run." is sage advice I'll never not forget.

Comment: how can one tell what is the correct `ENTRYPOINT` dll? I have mine exactly like what is show in the answer here (except `SampleAppForDocker.dll` named something else). Yet I'm still seeing the error from the title of this Stack Overflow question

Comment: I changed my entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["ls", "."]` which allowed me to see all the files in the directory and realise I was using an incorrect dll name

Comment: That's my problem here.. someone changed the AssemblyName property, like above, to "7".. so  "MyProject.dll" was never created.. because it was created as "7.dll".. LOL

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <AssemblyName>7</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: @PatNeedham Bit late, but to answer your question, in the .csproj there should be a `AssemblyName` node. That's the name of the generated DLL, which is the entrypoint :-)

Comment: @MathieuVIALES that was a lifetime ago, I already switched jobs lol

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue, but my `ENTRYPOINT` was correct. The issue was with stale or a corrupt `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1` image. So I purged everything and rebuilt the docker image.

For those unaware, this is how to do that:

```
Remove all docker containers: docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
Remove all docker images:     docker rmi -f $(docker images)
```

After that, it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

In case of `linux`, the case sensitivity is important. In my case the problem was with (btw. it was working as `Windows` container)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "backendapi.dll"]
```

as the library name was written with different case. It was fixed once the entrypoint got named correctly as

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BackendAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Linux: case, case, case. It is very easy to forget for a Windows developer.

Answer (score 5):

I followed the [.Net Core app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows) given by Microsoft, and ran into the same issue. I had the docker file set up as:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
COPY bin/release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NetCore.Docker.dll"]
```

but it did not pull the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet image to base my build on (I'm assuming, because I'm not an expert on this matter yet). I did a pull request for the aspnet image:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
```

and it created this image. I then built my project's docker image, and created my container. My container and app functioned as intended after the abovementioned.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the problem of working directory. 
In Dockerfile you should be in the same working directory where your execution dll is placed. As follows :
 [Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgfX4.png)

Answer (score 2):

On my case it was a space after double quotes:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", " MyAssembly.dll"]
```

After removing it it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and as it turned out, I had accidentally mounted the application path of the container to the host system:

```
# Dockerfile
# ...
WORKDIR /var/myapp
# ...
```

```
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  myapp:
    // ...
    volumes:
      - /c/docker/myapp:/var/myapp     // <--- Had to be removed
    ports:
      - "80:5000"
```

Changing the volumes mapping resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was not related to docker. The "arguments" attribute in web.config had an error, the name of dll was incorrect. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your dll is copied from the publishing location to `/app`. Maybe your publishing configuration overrides that.

As suggested by @KarlGreen, `ENTRYPOINT ["ls", "."]` shows you if the dll was actually copied to the `/app` folder. In my case it wasn't, `ls` only listed `web.config` and `wwwroot`. If I published the Debug configuration instead, then the dll *would* be copied so there's some difference in publishing configuration, although I'm not sure what exactly. The `output` option to the `publish` command was not honored, but overridden by something else unknown to me.

I worked around it by explicitly copying the release output with a copy command e.g.

```
COPY --from=build-env /app/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1 .
```

Answer (score 0):

For me is I forgot to copy published folder from the build step into the final step.

```
...
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish  --configuration Release --output /dist

FROM base AS final
COPY --from=publish /dist .
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was I keep the volume in my docker-compose

```
volumes:
  - ./NotificationService:/app
```

And when i executed the compose file the .dll no longer existed inside the container because they were replaced by the content of the app. So remove the volume if you want to executed the dll in ENTRYPOINT